# Pin description of Intel 8086

Tags: pins, intel

In the pin [diagram](http://scanftree.com/microprocessor/Pin-Diagram-of-8086-and-Pin-description-of-8086) of Intel 8086 microprocessor, There are two RD' and WR' pins which control the read from memory/IO or write to memory/IO. Also, there is another pin named DT/R which also control the direction. What is the difference between this pin and RD/WR? I think they are doing the same thing!

**UPDATE**

I want to know why another pin is needed for data direction. Is there any example or scenario which shows that a single RD' signal is not enough to determine the direction (memory to cpu); Hence we need another signal... Why we can not use RD'/WR' for the external transceiver? What happens if we remove DT/R?

Comment: The question can easily be answered by referring to the documentation. Question should be closed.

Comment: I have edited the question, as I didn't find the answer in the data sheet (at least this is what I understood from data sheet).

Comment: The question is not a RTFM one!

Answer (score 3):

Rule no.1>

When you want to know what is the difference between pins, or anything more detailed about an IC, you read the **datasheet** and **not** a short diagram and pin description. Because datasheets *are made to be read* and *any* information in short descriptions are *from* datasheets.

All information below is from
[Intel 8086 Datasheet](http://www.ece.cmu.edu/%7Eece740/f11/lib/exe/fetch.php?media=wiki:8086-datasheet.pdf)

**RD**
READ: Read strobe indicates that the processor is performing a
memory or I/O read cycle, depending on the state of the S2 pin. This
signal is used to read devices which reside on the 8086 local bus. RD
is active LOW during T2, T3 and TW of any read cycle, and is
guaranteed to remain HIGH in T2 until the 8086 local bus has floated.
This signal floats to 3-state OFF in ‘‘hold acknowledge’’.

**WR**
WRITE: indicates that the processor is performing a write memory or write
I/O cycle, depending on the state of the M/IO signal. WR is active for T2, T3
and TW of any write cycle. It is active LOW, and floats to 3-state OFF in
local bus ‘‘hold acknowledge’’

**DT/R** 
DATA TRANSMIT/RECEIVE: needed in minimum system that desires to
use an 8286/8287 data bus transceiver. It is used to control the direction of
data flow through the transceiver. Logically DT/R is equivalent to S1 in the
maximum mode, and its timing is the same as for M/IO. (T e HIGH, R e
LOW.) This signal floats to 3-state OFF in local bus ‘‘hold acknowledge’’

TLDR?
Read datasheets.
RD and WR pins are for RAM/IO communication.
DT/R is used to control 8286(7) data bus transceiver.

Comment: Still the question remains... I want to know why another pin is needed for data direction. Do you have any example or scenario which shows that a single RD' signal is not enough to determine the diection. Hence we need another signal... Why we can not use RD'/WR' for the external trasceiver?